# Prove that it is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that a line $l \in \mathbb{R^3}$ is a vector subspace if and only if $0\in l$. Generalize for $l\in \mathbb{R^n}$.

I started with the definition of vector subspace, it had to contains $0$. Also we could write a line in $\mathbb{R^3}$ like intersection of to plane so we have the known term equal to zero?
$(a_1-a_2)x+(b_1-b_2)y+(c_1-c_2)z+d_1+d_2=0$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Comment: This is bad. We require, like Alfred Hitchcock's _Psycho_, that you give context to questions you ask. This may be attempts at a solution, where the problem came from, etc. The question can be edited to add in this context.

Comment: Every vector subspace is closed under linear combinations so if $x\in l \quad \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ you need to have $\alpha x\in l$. Apply that for $\alpha=0$ and you have a side of the double implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $l \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a line, then there is $p \in \mathbb R^n$ and a subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $ \dim U=1$ and

$$l=p+U.$$

Then we have

$0 \in l \iff$ there is $u \in U$ such that $0=p+u \iff $ there is $u \in U$ such that $p=-u \iff p \in U \iff l=U.$